# How to get string from String.prototype

Tags: javascript, string, prototype

I want to write a `log` method for String that can print the `string`, but it not work on the correct way

```
String.prototype.log = () => console.log(this.toString())
'Print Me'.log()  // [object Window]
```

I want to print `Print Me`, not `[object Window]`, how can I make it work

Comment: Oh! shit, I get it, `this` not work on the arrow function

Answer (score 1):

Oh yes! It does. The error is that `this` doesn't point to the string in an arrow function:

```js
String.prototype.log = function() {
  console.log(this.toString())
}

'Print Me'.log();
```

You can see that it works when you do it using a regular function. You need to read more about lexical scoping of arrow functions.

Answer (score 1):

`this` in arrow functions belongs to the enclosing context. You shouldn't be using arrow function here since you will need to access the string object.

Make it

```
String.prototype.log = function() { console.log(this.toString()) }
```